# Spring Boot Actuator Integration with Non-Spring boot (Spring version 4.0.2) Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator, actuator

I am trying to integrate actuator in my spring mvc app (version 4.0.2) which is using java 7. I have xml based config. Without any sort of conflict and error, I can add below dependency -

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But actuator endpoint is not being enabled.

It would be highly appreciating if anyone can come up with a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Check this out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuator-without-spring-boot

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I tried it, but compatibility issue with spring 4.0.xx